# How to make font-lock use my face?

Tags: major-mode, font-lock

I'm interested in making a major mode to display [PGN files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Game_Notation) nicely.  I'm trying to create my own faces since the defaults don't seem super-appropriate.

My mode definition looks like this:

```
(defface my-r-face `((t (:foreground "red")))  "Red highlight")

(setq pgn-highlights
      '(("Pi\\|Infinity" . font-lock-constant-face)
    ("Sin\\|Cos" . font-lock-string-face)
    ("[0-9]+\\." . font-lock-keyword-face)
    ;; ("%.*" . my-r-face) ;; This doesn't show up (the relevant text appears just like the default text
    ("%.*" . font-lock-comment-face) ;; works great - relevant text looks like the comment face
    ))

(define-derived-mode pgn-mode fundamental-mode "mymath"
  "major mode for editing mymath language code."
  (setq font-lock-defaults '(pgn-highlights)))
```

A typical file that I'd like to use this on is:

```
[Event "?"]
[Site "?"]
[Date "2019.6.3"]
[Round "?"]
[White "Mike"]
[Black "Mikey"]
[Result "*"]
[WhiteELO "?"]
[BlackELO "?"]

%Created by Caissa's Web PGN Editor
1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bc4 Bc5 4. O-O Nf6 5. d3 d6 6. Nc3 a6 7. a3 Be6 8.
Bxe6 fxe6 9. h3 O-O 10. Be3 Ba7 11. Ra2 Qe8 12. Qc1 Nh5 13. Qd2 Nf4 14. g3
Nxh3+ 15. Kg2 Qh5 16. Rh1 Qxf3+ 17. Kh2 Nxf2 18. Rf1 Qh5+ 19. Kg2 Qf3+ 20.
Kg1 Qh1#
```

The issue is the line with the comment (`%Created by...`).  **If I use the built-in `font-lock-comment-face` then everything is highlighted nicely and the comment looks like the normal comment.  But if I change it to use `my-r-face`then the comment is *not* highlighted, and instead appears be be the default font face.**

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this, after the `defface`, to define a variable of the same name, whose value is the face symbol:

```lisp
(defvar my-r-face 'my-r-face
  "Variable for face `my-r-face'.)
```

`font-lock-defaults` in the case of just `(pgn-highlights)` defines `font-lock-keywords` as the list that is the value of variable `pgn-highlights`.

The [doc for **`font-lock-keywords`**](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Search_002dbased-Fontification.html) tells you about this case, which is the one you are using:

> `(MATCHER . FACESPEC)`
>
> In this kind of element, `FACESPEC` is an expression whose value
>   specifies the face to use for highlighting.  In the simplest case,
>   `FACESPEC` is **a Lisp variable** (a symbol) **whose value is a face name**.
>
> ```
>      ;; Highlight occurrences of ‘fubar’,
>      ;; using the face which is the value of ‘fubar-face’.
>      ("fubar" . fubar-face)
> ```

Comment: adding last quote fix typo error on defvar